# Как посмотреть отправляемый через curl post запрос

Tags: php, curl

отправляю на сервер пост-запрос с помощью курл.
Но постоянно выходит ошибка 500.
Заголовки все проверил, одинаковые с оригиналом. 
Грешу на отправляемые данные.

отправляю в виде: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login=login&password=111111&_token=token');`

Как посмотреть(вывести на экран), в каком виде уходят эти данные?

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = array('login' => 'login', 'password' => '111111', '_token' => 'token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

Так не пробовали?

Comment: пробовал. Результат тот же